# Connected to a tor relay failed (TLS_ERROR - 192.0.2.2:2). Error when trying to connect to tor

Tags: bridge, network-configuration, connection, tor-network

I am trying to connect to tor but I get the error: Connected to a tor relay failed (TLS_ERROR - 192.0.2.2:2)

I only get that error when using the meek-azure built-in bridge, when I use any other bridge or don't use a bridge at all it hangs on the "negotiating with a tor relay" stage.

When it hangs It eventually times out.

The network I am connecting from is trying to censor tor if that helps.

Tor logs:

```
4/28/22, 10:45:42.458 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:46:27.166 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:46:27.166 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges")
4/28/22, 10:46:31.511 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:46:31.512 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default")
4/28/22, 10:46:31.770 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:46:43.246 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:46:43.247 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:46:44.393 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport
4/28/22, 10:46:44.395 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport
4/28/22, 10:46:46.624 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:46.630 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:46.637 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:46.641 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:46.649 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:46.979 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 209.148.46.65:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=74FAD13168806246602538555B5521A0383A1875 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:47.170 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:47.336 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:49.454 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 51.222.13.177:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=5EDAC3B810E12B01F6FD8050D2FD3E277B289A08 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:49.458 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:49.734 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:49.738 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 209.148.46.65:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=74FAD13168806246602538555B5521A0383A1875 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:50.149 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:50.161 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:50.830 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:50.837 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.213 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 146.57.248.225:22 ID=<none> RSA_ID=10A6CD36A537FCE513A322361547444B393989F0 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.222 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 45.145.95.6:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.233 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 37.218.245.14:38224 ID=<none> RSA_ID=D9A82D2F9C2F65A18407B1D2B764F130847F8B5D ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.234 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27025 ID=<none> RSA_ID=1AE2C08904527FEA90C4C4F8C1083EA59FBC6FAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.234 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=2D82C2E354D531A68469ADF7F878FA6060C6BACA ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:52.235 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27020 ID=<none> RSA_ID=86AC7B8D430DAC4117E9F42C9EAED18133863AAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:54.291 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:54.616 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:54.618 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 209.148.46.65:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=74FAD13168806246602538555B5521A0383A1875 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:55.108 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:55.727 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:55.930 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:56.572 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27020 ID=<none> RSA_ID=86AC7B8D430DAC4117E9F42C9EAED18133863AAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:56.575 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27025 ID=<none> RSA_ID=1AE2C08904527FEA90C4C4F8C1083EA59FBC6FAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:56.595 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 37.218.245.14:38224 ID=<none> RSA_ID=D9A82D2F9C2F65A18407B1D2B764F130847F8B5D ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:56.598 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=2D82C2E354D531A68469ADF7F878FA6060C6BACA ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:57.216 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:57.331 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 146.57.248.225:22 ID=<none> RSA_ID=10A6CD36A537FCE513A322361547444B393989F0 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:57.336 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 45.145.95.6:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:57.530 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:46:59.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:00.496 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:00.701 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:00.947 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 209.148.46.65:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=74FAD13168806246602538555B5521A0383A1875 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:01.825 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 144.217.20.138:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=FB70B257C162BF1038CA669D568D76F5B7F0BABB ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:02.366 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:02.872 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 45.145.95.6:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:02.875 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 37.218.245.14:38224 ID=<none> RSA_ID=D9A82D2F9C2F65A18407B1D2B764F130847F8B5D ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:02.893 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:02.935 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:03.422 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:04.364 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 146.57.248.225:22 ID=<none> RSA_ID=10A6CD36A537FCE513A322361547444B393989F0 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:05.492 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.33.83:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=0BAC39417268B96B9F514E7F63FA6FBA1A788955 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:05.974 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:06.499 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=2D82C2E354D531A68469ADF7F878FA6060C6BACA ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:06.502 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27020 ID=<none> RSA_ID=86AC7B8D430DAC4117E9F42C9EAED18133863AAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:07.212 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:09.622 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 209.148.46.65:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=74FAD13168806246602538555B5521A0383A1875 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:09.662 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27025 ID=<none> RSA_ID=1AE2C08904527FEA90C4C4F8C1083EA59FBC6FAF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:10.240 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:10.666 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:10.673 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:10.679 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 45.145.95.6:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:13.490 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.26:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=91A6354697E6B02A386312F68D82CF86824D3606 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:13.522 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 146.57.248.225:22 ID=<none> RSA_ID=10A6CD36A537FCE513A322361547444B393989F0 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:13.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 192.95.36.142:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=CDF2E852BF539B82BD10E27E9115A31734E378C2 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:14.506 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:14.598 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 37.218.245.14:38224 ID=<none> RSA_ID=D9A82D2F9C2F65A18407B1D2B764F130847F8B5D ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:14.599 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 193.11.166.194:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=2D82C2E354D531A68469ADF7F878FA6060C6BACA ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:18.109 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 85.31.186.98:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=011F2599C0E9B27EE74B353155E244813763C3E5 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:18.542 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 38.229.1.78:80 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C8CBDB2464FC9804A69531437BCF2BE31FDD2EE4 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:18.629 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 45.145.95.6:27015 ID=<none> RSA_ID=C5B7CD6946FF10C5B3E89691A7D3F2C122D2117C ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:47:27.718 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:27.718 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:28.250 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:47:31.696 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:31.956 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:35.282 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:35.283 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:46.610 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:46.610 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:47.287 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:47:50.358 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:50.619 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:53.727 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:53.727 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:54.443 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
4/28/22, 10:47:55.383 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (TLS_ERROR; TLS_ERROR; count 1; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 192.0.2.2:2)
4/28/22, 10:47:55.384 [WARN] 70 connections have failed:
4/28/22, 10:47:55.384 [WARN] 69 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
4/28/22, 10:47:55.385 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
4/28/22, 10:47:55.422 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:55.423 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:47:56.297 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:47:59.253 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:47:59.254 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:48:01.335 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (TLS_ERROR; TLS_ERROR; count 2; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 192.0.2.2:2)
4/28/22, 10:48:01.336 [WARN] 71 connections have failed:
4/28/22, 10:48:01.336 [WARN] 69 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
4/28/22, 10:48:01.336 [WARN] 2 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
4/28/22, 10:48:01.353 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:48:01.353 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:48:02.295 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:48:43.749 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:48:44.725 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:48:47.487 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:49:01.306 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:49:02.673 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:49:02.673 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:49:04.200 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:04.200 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:05.130 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:05.140 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:06.130 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:06.140 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:07.210 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:07.210 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:09.370 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:09.370 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:12.560 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:12.560 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:17.100 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:17.100 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:22.137 [NOTICE] Bridge at '192.0.2.2:2' isn't reachable by our firewall policy. Asking bridge authority instead.
4/28/22, 10:49:22.138 [NOTICE] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6)
4/28/22, 10:49:25.542 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:49:25.542 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:49:26.297 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:49:29.254 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:50:27.916 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:50:48.420 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:50:53.820 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:50:53.821 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:50:54.947 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:55.904 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:56.911 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:57.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 176.58.96.180:8764 ID=<none> RSA_ID=AE21C8D9A2F7FAFC1A4A6E5E6477A9221D7490CD ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:57.254 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 80.67.177.138:7734 ID=<none> RSA_ID=60069916428A4F8AA64B1AC50B1B105263ADDDCF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:57.956 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:58.930 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:59.935 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:59.982 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 80.67.177.138:7734 ID=<none> RSA_ID=60069916428A4F8AA64B1AC50B1B105263ADDDCF ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:50:59.987 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 176.58.96.180:8764 ID=<none> RSA_ID=AE21C8D9A2F7FAFC1A4A6E5E6477A9221D7490CD ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:51:02.710 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 5.188.188.210:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=6138019DF8B380F48C8E9BC4551C7EE333322F97 ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:51:03.247 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with 176.58.96.180:8764 ID=<none> RSA_ID=AE21C8D9A2F7FAFC1A4A6E5E6477A9221D7490CD ("general SOCKS server failure")
4/28/22, 10:51:03.523 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:51:03.523 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:51:04.292 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:51:06.557 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:51:20.998 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:51:20.998 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:51:22.263 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (TLS_ERROR; TLS_ERROR; count 3; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 192.0.2.2:2)
4/28/22, 10:51:22.264 [WARN] 85 connections have failed:
4/28/22, 10:51:22.264 [WARN] 82 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
4/28/22, 10:51:22.265 [WARN] 3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
4/28/22, 10:51:22.275 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 10:51:22.275 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 10:51:22.286 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
4/28/22, 10:52:12.877 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
4/28/22, 11:02:41.510 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 11:02:41.512 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 11:02:43.760 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (TLS_ERROR; TLS_ERROR; count 4; recommendation warn; host 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE at 192.0.2.2:2)
4/28/22, 11:02:43.780 [WARN] 86 connections have failed:
4/28/22, 11:02:43.800 [WARN] 82 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
4/28/22, 11:02:43.820 [WARN] 4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
4/28/22, 11:02:43.119 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
4/28/22, 11:02:43.120 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
4/28/22, 11:02:43.524 [WARN] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The network **is** censoring your connection, that's in your log. You're absolutely right to attach a *full* log - that clarifies your question. Try to use Yggdrassil mesh Tor bridges or - if it works - a private OBFS4 ones. This bridge you're trying to use won't work - it's banned.

Comment: Is there some way I can set up a personal tor bridge over my home network? Also the torproject.org domain is not blocked, but has limited access and most of it is broken. Could this be a way it is being censored by creating a fake tor site maybe?